# Typescript: how to Exclude an interface with only optional properties from a union type

Tags: typescript

I have a few interfaces similar to these, where the interface that I want to later exclude consists of only optional properties:

```
interface P {
    id: string
}

interface A extends P {
    attrA: string
}

interface B extends P {
    attrB?: string
}
```

Now excluding this interface from a union with other interfaces doesn't work:

```
type R = Exclude<A | B, B> // expected: A, is: never
```

Type `R` is `never`, but should be `A`.

I can see that `Exclude<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T` and apparently `A extends B` is `true` if `B` consists only of optional properties. Why is that?

And how can I properly exclude a type from a union type of interfaces?

Comment: `P` and `A` and `B` are the same type.  TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing), not nominal.  That is: names don't define types, shapes do.  `Exclude<A | B, B>` is the same as `Exclude<A | A, A>` or `Exclude<A, A>` or `never`.

Comment: Thanks, that already makes it a bit clearer, but my actual types are not the same and it still shows as `never`. I will try to update the example with better types.

Comment: Yes, `A extends B` is considered true, since an object of type `A` is *almost* always assignable to a variable of type `B`, with the exception of something like `{id: "a", attrA: "a", attrB: 123}`, which requires subtraction/negation types to represent more soundly.  Can you just make sure `B` has a property that distinguishes it from `A`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given these types:

```
interface P {
    id: string
}

interface A extends P {
    attrA: string
}

interface B extends P {
    attrB?: string
}

type R = Exclude<A | B, B>; // never
```

The type `R` is `never` because `A extends B` is perceived by the compiler to be true:

```
const a: A = { id: "a", attrA: "A" };
const b: B = a; // okay
```

You can see that `a` is a valid `A`, but it's also a valid `B`.  Object types in TypeScript are not [exact](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936); you can extend a type by adding properties (which is why `A` is assignable to `P`, even though `A` has an extra property).  From the type system's point of view, every value of type `A` is also a value of type `B`, and so, `Exclude<A | B, B>` removes both `A` and `B` from the union and you are left with `never`.

---

Of course, it isn't actually type safe to have `A` assignable to `B`.  The compiler assumes that *every* value of type `A` is also of type `B`, but really it's more like *almost* every value.  There are some specific values of type `A` which are should not be assignable to type `B`, namely anything with an `attrB` property of an incompatible type:

```
const aButNotB = {id: "a", attrA: "A", attrB: 123}
const alsoA: A = aButNotB; // okay
const notB: B = aButNotB; // error, attrB is incompatible
const butWait: B = alsoA; // no error?! attrB is still incompatible, but compiler forgot!
```

But since TypeScript doesn't yet support [negated types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317#issuecomment-504379078), there's no way in TypeScript to represent "Every `A` which is not a `B`" as a concrete type.  And so, when comparing two object types, the compiler just ignores optional properties present in just one of them... leading to this blind spot.

---

So that's why it's happening.  As for how to fix this, it depends on your use case.

Ideally if you really need to be able to discriminate values of a union of types from each other, you would use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions).  This means the union should contain some property or properties which can be used to absolutely tell them apart from each other.  For example, let's imagine adding a `type` discriminant property:

```
interface Aʹ extends A {
  type: "A";
}

interface Bʹ extends B {
  type: "B";
}

type Rʹ = Exclude<Aʹ | Bʹ, Bʹ>; // Aʹ
```

Now there is no way for a value of type `Aʹ` to be assignable to type `Bʹ` or vice versa, and now `Exclude` behaves as you expect.

---

Or, if you're just looking at how to do the `Exclude` the way you expect, you can modify your `A` and `B` types before processing them, and then unmodify the result, like this:

```
type OptToUndef<T> = {
  [K in keyof Required<T>]: T[K] | ({} extends Pick<T, K> ? undefined : never)
};
type UndefToOpt<T> = (Partial<
  Pick<T, { [K in keyof T]: undefined extends T[K] ? K : never }[keyof T]>
> &
  Pick<
    T,
    { [K in keyof T]: undefined extends T[K] ? never : K }[keyof T]
  >) extends infer O
  ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] }
  : never;
```

Basically `OptToUndef<T>` takes an object type `T` and makes all optional types required but their property types include `undefined`.  And `UndefToOpt<T>` takes an object type `T` and makes all properties whose types include `undefined` into optional properties.  These are more-or-less inverse operations of each other (as long as you don't have *required* types including `undefined`).   Then you can do this:

```
type UA = OptToUndef<A>; // {id: string; attrA: string }
type UB = OptToUndef<B>; // {id: string; attrB: string | undefined }
type UR = Exclude<UA | UB, UB>; // same as UA
type Rfixed = UndefToOpt<UR>; // same as A
```

Something like that might work for you, where you tweak `B` to not be all-optional, and then un-tweak it when you're done.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//?target=6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArIN4FgBQznAAmAXMgM5hSgDmA3LgL666iSyIoCCyEAHpCEJk0mXPjhhKnUhSog6jZjlbR4SZACEe-CIOHpseZBMoaA-DMo16OJjlxgAngAcUAJWQBeZAFFeCABsAV0IIAB5uAB9NABpNAD5aZAB6ZOQQCAA3aCUEAHsQCmNSbm8MAhJkACI4KriTKGlqzirkBht8wrBkACNSLW84JNTkPIBrOEdcgqK4DSCwADk8sAHMCtIauuNJRs2W+t2NUgBGACYAZjaOme64ALI8ptLjeaWVjWG08cncTqKQB9+l5XgtlqsvjwoFA8lBDqYCMJQPkALbOCTAHoBCB-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-jBKEYS6ROFlxBZqYjGQcAoigcDCLppnuLuvD7t4hk3nkd4eW4flpAFQXGFauBAA)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the lengthy but complete explanation.